# How to clear class without setTimeout in jQuery

Tags: jquery, settimeout, addclass

I'm trying to bind every click on "body" with a little animation under the cursor:
http://jsfiddle.net/Nippon/pARR3/

```
var timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function(){
$(".click").removeClass("clickOn");
}, 1000);

$('html').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      $(".click").addClass("clickOn");
      clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
      setTimeout(function(){
$(".click").removeClass("clickOn");
}, 1000);
    });
```

The problem is that I don't know how to addClass and remove it on the same click. For now I'm using setTimeout and it's working for slow clicks and no double clicks. When you start clicking like a mad man animation is going to hell.

Can somebody help me to clean up this mess I've made and make it smooth/double-click-proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a slightly different approach. I created a new element for each click. Here are two options:

http://jsfiddle.net/kxJkK/

```
$(document).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
    $('#clickWrapper').css({
        left: e.pageX - 20,
        top: e.pageY - 20
    });
});

$('html').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $div = $('<div class="click"></div>')
        .appendTo('#clickWrapper')
        .addClass('clickOn');

    setTimeout(function () {
        $div.remove();
    }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KTdN7/

```
var left;
var top;

$(document).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
    left = e.pageX - 20,
    top = e.pageY - 20
});

$('html').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $div = $('<div class="click"></div>')
        .css({ top: top, left:left})
        .appendTo('#clickWrapper')
        .addClass('clickOn');

    setTimeout(function () {
        $div.remove();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: First one is perfect as animation is always under the cursor. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function(){
$(".click").removeClass("clickOn");
}, 1000);

$('html').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  $(".click").addClass("clickOn").delay(1000).removeClass("clickOn");
  clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
  setTimeout(function(){
$(".click").removeClass("clickOn");
}, 1000);
});
```

That should work. c

Comment: Thanks for your input, however Jason P solution is the one I was looking for - every click revokes animation from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent double clicks, you can simply remove the handler temporarily.  The same technique can be used if you later decide to temporarily stop watching mouse movements.  `setTimeout` is needed here, however.  Either directly used by you, or an internal library.

```
$(document).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
    $('#clickWrapper').css({
        left: e.pageX - 20,
        top: e.pageY - 20
    });
});

function toggleBubble(state) {
    if (state) {
        $(".click").addClass("clickOn");
        $('html').off('click', showBubble);
        console.log("add");
    } else {
        $(".click").removeClass("clickOn");
        $('html').on('click', showBubble);
        console.log("rm");
    }
}

function showBubble(e) {    
    toggleBubble(true);
    setTimeout(toggleBubble.bind(null, false), 1000);

    return false;
}

$('html').on('click', showBubble);
```

#### [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pARR3/4/)